# Efficient finite field multiplication with log-antilog-table lookup in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, modulo, finite-field

I am trying to implement efficient multiplication in GF(2^8), which elements are most naturally represented as uint8-numpy-values, in a numpy-thonic way. Therefore, I implemented GF-Arithmetics (in pure Python, not numpy) in order to build log-antilog-tables (I took a ranom generator, 9); in particular, I implemented a (non-numpy) Python-Function `multGF` which implements GF-Multiplication, which works great but is slow (since it uses polynomial modulo calcs). A common trick to speed up multiplication is to use the following equation:

[image]

Building the log-antilog-`uint8`-ndarrays is easily performed like this:

```
gen = 9 ; K = [1] ; g = gen
for i in range(1,255): 
    K.append(g)
    g = multGF(g,gen)

antilog = np.array(K, dtype='uint8')

log = np.full(256,0, dtype='uint8')
for i in range(255): log[antilog[i]] = i
```

But, and that is my question, how to implement the multiplication in a numpy-thonic way? Both, the log table and the antilog table are of size 255 (not 256; no log for 0) and the exponents have to be added modulo 255 - and not mod 256. I came up with the following IMHO non numpy-thonic solution:

```
def multGF2(a,b): 
    return antilog[(int(log[a]) + log[b]) % 255]
```

I had to convert the uint8-addition (which works mod-256 naturally) into an int-addtion in order to perform mod-255-addition. This is neither elegant nor efficient and I am quite sure, that any has a better solution?

For testing: here are both logtables as arrays:

```
log = [  nan   0 250 214 245 173 209  42 240   1 168  71 204 187  37 132 235  91
 251 191 163  84  66 146 199 212 182 215  32  30 127 247 230 206  86 229
 246  65 186 244 158  87  79 171  61 174 141 180 194 113 207  50 177 150
 210  54  27 105  25 231 122  93 242  43 225   2 201 156  81 142 224  52
 241  53  60  64 181 190 239 254 153 119  82  72  74   9 166  62  56  13
 169 143 136  34 175 109 189  80 108 165 202 188  45  99 172 203 145 126
 205 157  49  24  22 139 100 159  20 111 226 133 117 233  88  46 237 130
 38   3 220 217 252  35 196  96 151  89  76   6 137 192 219   5  47 178
 236 110  48  98  55 118  59 155 176  92 185 179 234 211 249  70 148  18
 114  39  77 124  67  14  69  58   4 195 161   7  57 147  51 238   8 135
 164 144 138 116 131 208  29 162 170  85 104 193 184  97  75 216 103 115
 160 123 197  11 183  10  40 222  94 101 167 213 198  90 140 243 121 149
 200  63 152  12  44  23  19 129  17  68 134  28  95 218 154 248  15  16
 106 227 221 102 128 120 112  26 228  78  83  31  41  36 232  21 125 107
 33  73 253 223]


antilog = [  1   9  65 127 170 141 137 173 178  85 203 201 219  89 167 232 233 224
 161 222 116 249 112 221 111  58 241  56 227 186  29 245  28 252  93 131
 247  14 126 163 204 246   7  63 220 102 123 142 146 110  51 176  71  73
 55 148  88 174 169 150  74  44  87 217  75  37  22 166 225 168 159  11
 83 253  84 194 136 164 243  42  97  68  82 244  21 189  34  41 122 135        
 211  17 153  61 206 228 133 193 147 103 114 207 237 196 190  57 234 251
 98  95 145 117 240  49 162 197 183 120 149  81 239 214  60 199 165 250
 107  30 238 223 125 184  15 119 226 179  92 138 182 113 212  46  69  91
 181 106  23 175 160 215  53 134 218  80 230 151  67 109  40 115 198 172
 187  20 180  99  86 208  10  90 188  43 104   5  45  94 152  52 143 155
 47  76  26 202 192 154  38  13 101  96  77  19 139 191  48 171 132 200
 210  24 216  66 100 105  12 108  33  50 185   6  54 157  25 209   3  27
 195 129 229 140 128 236 205 255  70  64 118 235 242  35  32  59 248 121
 156  16 144 124 177  78   8  72  62 213  39   4  36  31 231 158   2  18
 130 254  79  ]
```

Comment: First of, it it faster if you skip the module, by doing plus with 'int' and then "doubling" your log-table. But for GF(2^8) it is even better (faster) to implement it by a multiplication table, with 256 rows and columns. This only take up 65536 bytes, if stored properly.